# Response::download make data in txt file loss

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have abc.txt on the public path and it contain string "Hello World" (line 1)

After I use

```
return Response::download(public_path()."/file/abc.txt");
```

the file will download correctly to browser (Chrome & Firefox) but data in file will change to

```
Hello Wor
```

And have invisible string in line 1 (not sure it is \r\n) and "Hello Wor" move to line 2

I use

```
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain');
    return Response::download(public_path() ."/file/abc.txt","abc.txt",$headers);
```

But problem not to resolved. Sorry for my bad grammar in English. 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you see if you open the file, read its contents as a string and output it in your browser using dd()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I can solve my problem by this code...

```
$res = Response::download(public_path() ."/file/abc.txt","abc.txt",$headers);
ob_end_clean();
return $res;
```

It clear.